# Is "ALL CAPS"-handwriting mandatory in aviation?

Tags: regulations

All caps handwriting increase clarity and visual impact, engineers, architects, people from military mostly write in all caps.
I know lot of old school-engineers that handwrite in all caps, because in technical drawing it is mandatory.

Is writing in all caps regulated in aviation ?

(Do aerospace engineers mostly handwrite in all caps?)

Comment: The FAA requires that flight progress strips be marked using capital letters (with some exceptions to avoid misinterpretation, for example the letter "U" is written with a "tail"). [7110.65 FIG 2–3–1.](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_3.html)

Comment: As Randomhead's comment highlights, "aviation" is an extremely broad category...  I can add that aircraft equipment certification plans and test reports are written in standard English without "yelling" in all caps.

Comment: Related: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/64367/29719

Comment: Aircraft accident voice recording transcripts are written in all lower case.

Answer (score 2):

**The Question Title:** *Is "ALL CAPS"-handwriting mandatory in aviation?*

**The Question within the text:** *Is writing in all caps **regulated** in aviation ?*

**Answer**: There is no  U.S. FAR (Federal Aviation Regulation) that mandates using all CAPS in aviation writing.

In some segments of aviation there may be policies or mandates for the use of all CAPS in certain types of writing, but I cannot locate a "Regulation" (i.e.,  U.S. Federal Aviation Regulation) that mandates this.

Comment: “Aviation” as a broad term does not equate to FAA regulations. @757toga are you able to expand on your answer?

Comment: @tedioustortoise My answer seems to respond directly to the question.  "*Is writing in all caps **regulated** in aviation?*"  My answer is that there is no regulation (U.S. Federal Aviation Regulation) that mandates writing in all CAPS.  I don't know how I can expand on that.  In some segments of aviation there may be policies for the use of all CAPS in certain types of writing, but I cannot locate a "Regulation" (i.e. FAR) that mandates this.

Comment: Expanding on that would be suggesting, for example, that there are any ICAO, EASA, or other regulatory body regulations. “In aviation” does not just mean the USA or FAA. Aviation is global. The FAA surely cannot to be the sole reference when such a broad question is asked about “aviation.” (And it peeves non U.S. participants of this site! :) )

Comment: @tedioustortoise I don't know if there are any EASA or ICAO regulations governing the use of all CAPS. This is why I specifically limited my answer  to **U.S. FAA regulations**. On this site it's perfectly acceptable to provide partial answers to questions and those reading the answer can value or not value the information provided in the answer.

Comment: but you’re underlying assumption is that the person asking the question would find a USA based answer helpful. It’s the unabashed arrogance of this assumption which is most irritating for non US users of this site.

Comment: @tedioustortoise - As you've correctly pointed out, the question has an extremely broad scope.  In providing a limited-to-the-USA answer, the assumption isn't "the question asker may find a USA scoped answer helpful" but "at least one person who finds this question in the future may find a USA scoped answer helpful".  That's why there's a distinction between the "upvote" button (for the general audience) and the "accept answer" button (for the asker).